# Unexpected behavior related to write() function

Tags: c, gcc, serial-port, embedded, cygwin

This program is intended to read a byte from the console (cygwin on windows XP) and write it to the serial port (in order to communicate from a PC to an AVR). Then it should read data from the serial port. The AVR is set up to send data periodically, which works as it should (confirmed with Hyper Terminal). The program below works as it should, but when the line that writes data to the serial port is commented out, the program does not read either. In fact, it does not execute the lines before the (commented out) "write (fd, datatemp, 1);" either.

Why does the program seemingly not execute as intended when the write operation is not included?

```
#include "serialport.h"
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/* baudrate settings are defined in <asm/termbits.h>, which is
 * included by <termios.h> */
#ifndef BAUDRATE
#define BAUDRATE B2400
#endif

#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1     /* POSIX compliant source */
#define BUFLEN 4

static int fd, c, res;
static struct termios oldtio, newtio;
static char *device;

int serial_init(char *modemdevice)
{
    /* 
     * Open modem device for reading and writing and not as controlling tty
     * because we don't want to get killed if linenoise sends CTRL-C.
     **/
    device = modemdevice;
    fd = open (device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    //fd = open (device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    //fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
    if (fd < 0)
      {
      perror (device);
      exit(-1);
      }

    tcgetattr (fd, &oldtio);    /* save current serial port settings */
    bzero (&newtio, sizeof (newtio));   /* clear struct for new port settings */

    /* 
     *BAUDRATE: Set bps rate. You could also use cfsetispeed and cfsetospeed.
     *CRTSCTS : output hardware flow control (only used if the cable has
     *all necessary lines. )
     *CS8     : 8n1 (8bit,no parity,1 stopbit)
     *CLOCAL  : local connection, no modem contol
     *CREAD   : enable receiving characters
     **/
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;

    /*
     *IGNPAR  : ignore bytes with parity errors
     *ICRNL   : map CR to NL (otherwise a CR input on the other computer
     *          will not terminate input)
     *          otherwise make device raw (no other input processing)
     **/
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;

    /*
     * Map NL to CR NL in output.
     *                  */
#if 0
    newtio.c_oflag = ONLCR;
#else
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
#endif


    /*
     * ICANON  : enable canonical input
     *           disable all echo functionality, and don't send signals to calling program
     **/
#if 1
    newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;
#else
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;
#endif

    /* 
     * initialize all control characters 
     * default values can be found in /usr/include/termios.h, and are given
     * in the comments, but we don't need them here
     *                                       */
    newtio.c_cc[VINTR] = 0; /* Ctrl-c */
    newtio.c_cc[VQUIT] = 0; /* Ctrl-\ */
    newtio.c_cc[VERASE] = 0;    /* del */
    newtio.c_cc[VKILL] = 0; /* @ */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOF] = 4;  /* Ctrl-d */
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* inter-character timer unused */
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;  /* blocking read until 1 character arrives */
    newtio.c_cc[VSWTC] = 0; /* '\0' */
    newtio.c_cc[VSTART] = 0;    /* Ctrl-q */
    newtio.c_cc[VSTOP] = 0; /* Ctrl-s */
    newtio.c_cc[VSUSP] = 0; /* Ctrl-z */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOL] = 0;  /* '\0' */
    newtio.c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;  /* Ctrl-r */
    newtio.c_cc[VDISCARD] = 0;  /* Ctrl-u */
    newtio.c_cc[VWERASE] = 0;   /* Ctrl-w */
    newtio.c_cc[VLNEXT] = 0;    /* Ctrl-v */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOL2] = 0; /* '\0' */

    /* 
     * now clean the modem line and activate the settings for the port
     **/
    tcflush (fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

    /*
     * terminal settings done, return file descriptor
     **/

    return fd;
}

void serial_cleanup(int ifd){
    if(ifd != fd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WARNING! file descriptor != the one returned by serial_init()\n");
    }
    /* restore the old port settings */
    tcsetattr (ifd, TCSANOW, &oldtio);
}

void main(void) {
    int fd = serial_init("/dev/ttyS0");

    //while(1)
    //{

        printf("Enter a dutycycle: ");
        unsigned char buffer[BUFLEN] = {0};
        fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin);
        uint8_t data = atoi(buffer);
        unsigned char datatemp[1] = {(unsigned char) data};

        printf("hen");
        write (fd, datatemp, 1);

        int n = 0;
        unsigned char inbuffer[2] = {0};
        int temp = -1;
        //printf("%ld", temp);
        while (temp <= 0)
        {
            //printf("%ld", temp);
            temp = read(fd, inbuffer, 1);

        }
        printf("%u", (uint8_t) inbuffer[0]);

    //}

    serial_cleanup(fd);
}
```

Comment: try adding newlines on `printf` function calls, eg. `printf("hen\n");` instead of `printf("hen");` to be sure where the program stops executing instructions

Comment: @guillem is correct; it's possible the `printf` is buffering output and you're just not seeing it. Use some `\n`.

Comment: Let debug output always go to `stderr` as its not buffered: `fprintf(stderr, ....`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at fflush() function.

Maybe

```
fflush(NULL)
```

or even

```
fflush(stdout)
```

will help in your case. Its worth experimenting by flushing before and/or after outputting to console.